# On server startup NPM find start script

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I'm working with docker and I'm wondering how I can get the command `npm start` to locate the `app.js` file without me doing it via the command line.

my package.json (located: `/srv/www`) looks as so:

```
{
  "name": "dist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "forever start -c \"nodemon --harmony\" app.js --exitcrash"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I'm currently invoking my docker image as so:

```
docker run -d -v /srv/docker/instantynode/srv:/srv -p 80:8080 myimg ???
```

I am hoping to replace the ??? with a command which will startup `node` and invoke `npm start` in the correct directory, any ideas?

I was thinking maybe of making a little startup script to fix this however I was wondering if npm can fix this on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding node application, you can start with `ONBUILD` in Dockerfile, so you can try as below:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM node:0.10-onbuild   (or version 0.12, depend your request)

PORT 8000
```

the image `node:0.10-onbuild` has codes already as below:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ONBUILD COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN npm install
ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["npm" "start"]
```

With `ONBUILD`, during `docker build`, your node.js (or angularjs) codes will be not copied to image and `npm install` doesn't run.

But when you run the container, it starts to copy the files to /usr/src/app and install npm package. Then start npm service.

So in your case, you should be fine to run your application directly without mount the volume every time.

```
# I guess file package.json is under /srv/docker/instantynode/srv
$ cd /srv/docker/instantynode/srv
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM node:0.10-onbuild

PORT 8000
$ docker build -t myimg .  
$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 myimg
```

That's all, you should be fine to access your application via port 8000 now.